# Find some by array of ids dynamically

Tags: arrays, sorting, arraylist, filter, array-filter

This is an example of code:-

`projects` array:-

```js
let projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Project 1',
        techs: [
            { id: 1a, name: 'Tech 1' }, { id: 1b, name: 'Tech 2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Project 2',
        techs: [
            { id: 1b, name: 'Tech 2' }, { id: 1c, name: 'Tech 3' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Project 3',
        techs: [
            { id: 1c, name: 'Tech 3' }, { id: 1d, name: 'Tech 4' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Project 4',
        techs: [
            { id: 1d, name: 'Tech 1' }, { id: 1e, name: 'Tech 5' }
        ]
    }
]
```

Right now my code look like this:-

```js
// get projects that have tech of ids of '1a' and '1d'
let filteredProjs = projects.filter(proj => proj.techs.some(tech => tech.id === '1a' || tech.id === '1d'))

console.log(filteredProjs) // Will give me 'Project 1', 'Project 3', and 'Project 4'
```

It works. But how can i make this become more dynamic instead of having to insert the some `condition` manually? (Eg: `tech.id === '1a' || tech.id === '1d'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array of techs that you want to look for, and then filter based on whether that array includes the current `tech.id` value:

```
// get projects that have tech of ids of '1a' and '1d'
let techs = ['1a', '1d'];
let filteredProjs = projects.filter(proj => proj.techs.some(tech => techs.includes(tech.id)));
```

```js
let projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Project 1',
        techs: [
            { id: '1a', name: 'Tech 1' }, { id: '1b', name: 'Tech 2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Project 2',
        techs: [
            { id: '1b', name: 'Tech 2' }, { id: '1c', name: 'Tech 3' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Project 3',
        techs: [
            { id: '1c', name: 'Tech 3' }, { id: '1d', name: 'Tech 4' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Project 4',
        techs: [
            { id: '1d', name: 'Tech 1' }, { id: '1e', name: 'Tech 5' }
        ]
    }
]

// get projects that have tech of ids of '1a' and '1d'
let techs = ['1a', '1d'];
let filteredProjs = projects.filter(proj => proj.techs.some(tech => techs.includes(tech.id)));

console.log(filteredProjs)
```

Comment: how can i not think of that? Thanks!